# Data disappears when switching between view controllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I am writing an iPhone application using the storyboards for an initial mockup. The problem I have right now is switching view controllers.

I have a table view controller and another view controller. All I want to do is use a back button to go back to the original screen, and I can do that, except the data disappears. The storyboard that I have is shown below. [image]

I have the Back button going back to the original navigation controller. I have also had it going back to the Card view controller.

I have hard coded some example cells to just see how things look and they show up just fine when I run the simulation. When I click the back button though, it goes back to the All Cards screen and the cells that were there are now gone.

If I need to post some code just ask for what part would be helpful, I have done all of this through storyboards though.

I'm sure it's something stupid I've done, any point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically: you pushed where you should have popped.

What you are seeing on the Storyboard does not exist yet. By segue-waying during runtime to a view controller it gets instantiated.

When you segue-wayed during runtime from the *Add Card* view controller "back" to the *Card View Controller* - here is what happened: instead of popping the navigation stack all the way back to the *Card View Controller* you already had, you just instantiated a new *Card View Controller* and pushed it onto the navigation stack. You could verify that by going all the way back to the original *Card View Controller* by tapping the back button several times.

What you could do to accomplish your task is this:
Instead of using the Storyboard for your back button use an IBAction in code:

```
- (IBAction)popToRoot:(id)sender {

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Ah. That makes perfect sense. I did not even think about that. So it goes with the first attempt at storyboards. Side question: Do I need a class for each view controller I have? i.e. I have the Home view and add card view here and i'll have two more views. Do each one need a view controller class and its own nav controller too?

Comment: My mistake. I didn't look close enough at your screenshot. 1) You only need one Navigation Controller. 2) Any View Controller in the storyboard already has a class (i.e. UIViewController). You only need to give it a custom class if you want to add functionality (like an IBAction in code)

Comment: To get "deeper" into your navigation stack just connect the content view controllers via a push segue. To pop back to the root view controller use the mentioned IBAction.

Comment: To get a good understanding on how that all works out in general I can highly recommend the Stanford University lectures on that topic: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/ (They are for free on iTunes University)

Comment: Okay, one navigation controller made more sense but I put in the second one and it didn't yell at me so I wasn't sure.

I believe I get it now, thank you so much for the answers. Those lectures look great, i'll get started!